# Maximum number of non pawn pieces in Chess

Tags: chess

In a game of chess with standard rules, what is the maximum number of queens, rooks, bishops, knights, and kings both black and white that can be on the board?

Comment: by 'can be on the board' you mean with or without any check-mate situation?

Comment: Is the question for queens equivalent to this one on chess stack exchange: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/maximum-number-of-queens-possible ?

Comment: @EmreÜnsal it can end in a checkmate or it cannot but it plays by normal rules so you can't ignore a check or anything like that

Comment: @hexomino I believe this number would by higher as you are not forced to sacrifice all your bishops and knights like you do in the queen example

Answer (score 10):

The anwser is:

> 28

My first though was

> 32 (every pawn is promoted to another piece by reaching the bank rank)
>  But the pawns can't pass trough the enemy pawns that are on the same file. All the other pieces can move away though.

So:

> The pawns can side step the enemy by capturing (lets say from the a-file to the b-file).
>  Which will reduce the total by one. But will let the enemy pawn on the a-file through and let the two friendly pawns on b-file through. 
> So one pawn is sacrificed, allowing the remaining a-file and b-file pawns to be promoted.

Now we just repeat this:

> pawn on c-file hits pawn on d-file 
>  pawn on e-file hits pawn on f-file 
>  pawn on g-file hits pawn on h-gile

So in total:

> We have to sacrifice 4 pawns which gives us a total of 28 non-pawn pieces.

Comment: This is just getting the pawns to the other side of the board, this doesn't say where to move the rest of the pieces to avoid a checkmate in that situation.

Comment: @Jon.G That wasn't part of the question.  But, by keeping each colour's Kings, Rooks & Knights to opposite corners of the board, putting Bishops & Queens in the remaining two corners, the options for two **cooperating** players to achieve this without checkmate are essentially trivial - only Queens can then threaten the King, and the Rooks/Knights can be use as a wall to prevent Check

Comment: @Chronocidal standard rules include checkmate.

Comment: @Jon.G Standard rules include Checkmate as a winning/losing position.  However, the Standard Rules don't actually say that you *have* to [play to win](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_Performance_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)).  Both players may intentionally be avoiding checkmate.

Comment: @Chronocidal this is intended for cooperative play, it doesn't make much sense if you were playing to win

Comment: This answer is very hard to read, because you mixed up rows and columns. Also in [chess terminology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard) they are called ranks and files respectively. Finally files are referenced by letters from A to H, while numbers are used for ranks.

Comment: @Sleafar I did not know this. Your welcome to edit my answer :)

Comment: Everything you need to know is in my comment above. If you want to know more, just follow the link.